# Perl - built-in function to "zipper" together two arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, merge

I want to merge two arrays of equal length into a single array by taking the first element from array A, the first element from array B; second element from A, second element from B, etc.  The following program illustrates the algorithm:

```
# file zipper.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @keys   = qw/abel baker charlie dog easy fox/;
my @values = qw/a b c d e f/;

# ==> Is there a builtin function that is equivalent of zipper()? <==
#
my %hash = zipper( \@keys, \@values );

while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %hash ) {
    say "$k=$v";
}

# zipper(): Take two equal-length arrays and merge them (one from A, one from B,
# another from A, another from B, etc.) into a single array.
#
sub zipper {
    my $k_ref = shift;
    my $v_ref = shift;
    die "Arrays must be equal length" if @$k_ref != @$v_ref;
    my $i = 0;
    return map { $k_ref->[ $i++ ], $_ } @$v_ref;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./zipper.pl 
easy=e
dog=d
fox=f
charlie=c
baker=b
abel=a
```

I'm wondering if I've overlooked a builtin function in Perl that will do the equivalent of zipper().  It will be at the innermost loop of the program, and needs to run as fast as possible.  If there's not a built-in or a CPAN module, can anyone improve upon my implementation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Others have given good answers for mesh/zip side of the question, but if you are just creating a hash from an array of keys and one of values you can do it with the under-appreciated [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys   = qw/abel baker charlie dog easy fox/;
my @values = qw/a b c d e f/;

my %hash;
@hash{@keys} = @values;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

**Addendum**

I got to thinking why one may choose one method over the other. I personally think that the slice implementation is as readable as the zip, but others may disagree. If you are doing this often, you may care about speed, in which case the slice form is faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

my @keys   = qw/abel baker charlie dog easy fox/;
my @values = qw/a b c d e f/;

cmpthese( 100000, {
  zip => sub {
    my %hash = zip @keys, @values;
  },
  slice => sub {
    my %hash;
    @hash{@keys} = @values;
  },
});
```

results:

```
         Rate   zip slice
zip   51282/s    --  -34%
slice 78125/s   52%    --
```

Comment: Very nice indeed.  And as usual, rather than asking the real question, I assumed a solution and then phrased the question that way.  Your solution is undoubtedly the best way to go.  Further revelation: I'm actually trying to initialize a Tie::IxHash - I've been using the OO form, and I don't believe it supports the hash slice, but for my purposes I think the simple non-OO interface would be fine.

Comment: I should also say, I know that lots of people dislike how the sigils change in Perl, but I think that in this case it really helps to visually inspect what is occurring. Maybe its just me :-)

Answer (score 11):

Since you offered a CPAN idea, there is [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) and `zip`.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

my @keys   = qw/abel baker charlie dog easy fox/;
my @values = qw/a b c d e f/;

my @zipped = zip @keys, @values;
```

The contents of `@zipped` would be:

```
abel, a, baker, b, charlie, c, dog, d, easy, e, fox, f
```

The nice part about using this method is you can zip more than two lists if you wish.  Since Perl has no concept of a tuple type, it is almost like a flattening operation.

Comment: I'm combining keys and values into a single array, which when assigned to a hash initializes the hash to those key=value pairs.  In reality I'll just assign the list returned from zip directly to the hash.

Comment: You can do that. `my %hash = zip @keys, @values;`. But if you're making a hash, why not just use a slice? `my %hash; @hash{@keys} = @values;`

Comment: nm, just saw @Joel's answer.

Comment: @friedo The question was a little confusing to me. I wasn't sure if the poster wanted an array or a hash as the result.  His code said one thing and words another.

Comment: I thought I required an array in order to initialize a hash, so in my attempt to simplify the question I actually obscured it!  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Although this specific function already exists in List::MoreUtils, you can use prototypes to give your own array functions the appearance of built-in array operators (like `push`, `shift`, `pop`):

```
sub zipper (++) {  # perldoc perlsub
  my ($k, $v) = @_;
  die "Arrays must be equal length" if @$k != @$v;
  my $i;
  return map { $k->[$i++], $_ } @$v
}

%hash = zipper @keys, @values;
%hash = zipper \@keys, \@values;
%hash = zipper $key_aref, $value_aref;
```

Comment: A note about the prototype: I agree that `+` is preferable to `\@`, but the former is only available since v14. The `+` prototype also accepts any scalar, or takes a reference when presented an `@array` or `%hash` variable. It may be cleaner to not use it here.

Comment: @amon, since prototypes aren't about strictness or typechecking in Perl, I don't mind the possibility of a hash. But the version requirement is funny--I only use systemperl in one-liners, so I forgot to consider when that feature was added.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use List::MoreUtils ( or List::AllUtils ) to gain access to mesh aka zip see [https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#mesh-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#mesh-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3)

Comment: "mesh" - ah, thanks for giving me the term I was looking for.