# Trying to Use Perl to Join Two Arrays at each Element

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I want to join two arrays together at the same element. For example, I want to combine $array1[0] and $array2[0] and so on down the road.

```
@array1 = qw(A B C D)
@array2 = qw(a b c d)

@array3 = qw(A a B b C c D d)
```

I tried previously to use an embedded loop, but that just produced the wrong output.

```
foreach my $liginfo_data_var (@liginfo_data)
{
    foreach my $ligands_data_var (@ligands_data)
    {
        print COMBLIG join ($liginfo_data_var, "\t", $ligands_data_var, "\n");

    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find an answer yet on StackOverflow and would hope to hear some suggestions. Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl - built-in function to "zipper" together two arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755642/perl-built-in-function-to-zipper-together-two-arrays)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Aah, how easy this would be in Perl6: `@array3 = @array1 Z @array2`)

Do not iterate over the *elements* directly. Instead, loop over the *indices* of both arrays in parallel:

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#array1 ) {
  push @array3, $array1[$i], $array2[$i];
}
```

Or with `map`: `@array3 = map { $array1[$_], $array2[$_] } 0 .. $#array1`.

This works fine if both input arrays have the same length. You can also `use List::MoreUtils 'zip'`: `@array3 = zip @array1, @array2`.

But it seems you don't want to create an `@array3`. If you just want to print out both elements:

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#array1 ) {
  say COMBLIG $array1[$i], "\t", $array2[$i];
}
```

Notice that I don't have to use `join`. That function concatenates an input list with a certain separator, which is given as fist argument. E.g. `join ', ', 1..3` produces `"1, 2, 3"`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I ended up using your last suggestion. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example straight out of the documentation for [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm):

```
use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise';

@a = qw/a b c/;
@b = qw/1 2 3/;
@x = pairwise { ($a, $b) } @a, @b;  # returns a, 1, b, 2, c, 3
```

**EDIT:** As ikegami pointed out, `zip` is a better solution:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'zip';

@a = qw/a b c/;
@b = qw/1 2 3/;
@x = zip @a, @b;  # returns a, 1, b, 2, c, 3
```

I ran a benchmark comparing `zip`, `pairwise`, and amon's `map` solution, all of which return a new array. `pairwise` was the hands-down loser:

```
             Rate pairwise      map      zip
pairwise 111982/s       --     -43%     -52%
map      196850/s      76%       --     -16%
zip      235294/s     110%      20%       --
```

Comment: @ikegami Yep, just discovered `zip` thanks to @amon's answer and the answer @squiguy linked to in the comments. Not only is `zip` slightly easier to read in this case, it's also a hell of a lot faster. Thanks for the tip.