# How do I declare and initialize a hash from two lists (keys and values)?

Tags: perl

I seem to recall seeing some syntax recently that let you do something like this

```
my %hash; @hash{@keys} = @values;
```

in one statement.  I tried the obvious

```
my %hash{@keys} = @values;
```

But that produced a syntax error.  Was I just dreaming, or is there a new syntax for that?

Comment: I am inclined to close this as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755642/100754).

Comment: perl6 could probably do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %hash = map +($keys[$_] => $values[$_]), 0 .. $#keys;
```

Or, you can use `List::MoreUtils::zip`, but I suspect `@hash{@keys} = @values` will be more efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys = ('a' .. 'z');
my @values = map ord, @keys;

my %map = map +($keys[$_] => $values[$_]), 0 .. $#keys;

use YAML::XS;
print Dump \%map;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about those, I just thought I had seen a new syntax (à la hash slices) that let you do the equivalent thing without an additional expression like map or zip.

Comment: Are you thinking of [Key/Value Hash Slices](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldata#Key/Value-Hash-Slices)? I haven't used them. I am not sure if they can be used to do this.

Comment: It might be that, or it might have been something in Perl 6.  I am starting to think I imagined the whole thing. I just went through the last four perldeltas and I didn't see anything obvious about it.

Comment: There is also [this](https://redd.it/5y3qwk).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip); # Here is another way to make a hash. 
# If you forgot how to install the module if it didn't come with your system perl, it's easy ...
# cpan install List::MoreUtils 
# Do that in your terminal. 

# I decided to reverse the letters and the numbers so I could show you how to sort it the hash. 
my @letters = reverse('A' .. 'Z');
my @numbers = reverse(1 .. 26);
my %Hash;

# You can make a hash like this from arrays of equal sizes. 
@Hash{@letters} = @numbers; 

say "\n Here is the hash formed standardly";
foreach(sort{$a cmp $b} keys %Hash)
{
    say "$_ => $Hash{$_}";
}

%Hash = zip(@letters, @numbers);
say "\nHere is the hash formed using the zip function";
foreach(sort{$a cmp $b} keys %Hash)
{
    say "$_ => $Hash{$_}";
}
```

Comment: That reverse does nothing useful.  The hash will already be in a random order (untied hashes can't preserve order). Also, none of this is new syntax.